# is there a way of refreshing the whole UITableView through a button that is in one of the cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift-protocols

I have a dynamically generated UITableView with many dynamic `UITableViewCells` and one static `UITableViewCell`.

The static one has a button and I want to refresh the whole table view when user presses it.

My code attached to the cell is simple:

```
class MyStaticCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var sendCommentButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func sendCommentButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {

        //from here I want to refresh the table

    }
}
```

How can I refresh the parent table from that button? In the class `MyStaticCell` I don't have any instance of the table, so that's my problem for now :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could access the tableView using superview.

```
class MyStaticCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var sendCommentButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func sendCommentButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {

        (superview as? UITableView)?.reloadData()
    }
}
```

This isn't as stable as it could be so maybe consider this extension:

```
extension UIResponder {

    func nextResponder<T: UIResponder>(ofType type: T.Type) -> T? {

        switch nextResponder() {

        case let responder as T:
            return responder

        case let .Some(responder):
            return responder.nextResponder(ofType: type)

        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

It allows you to find the next parent of a particular type, in the cells case, a `UITableView`.

```
class MyStaticCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var sendCommentButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func sendCommentButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {

        nextResponder(ofType: UITableView.self)?.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man for a good clarification. I just realized that refreshing the table is not enough for me since I need to fetch new data from the server and then refresh the table... I already have methods for that in my parent UITableViewController, so I could just call them on the button press. Is there a way of calling the method from parent component while accessing it from within the cell?

Comment: Yup just use `nextResponderOfType(ParentViewController.self)?.parentMethod()`

Answer (score 3):

The cleanest way to do this is through delegation.  This ensures that the cell class doesn't need to know what should happen when the button is pressed; that logic can remain in your view controller where it belongs.

```
protocol CommentButtonProtocol {

    func commentButtonTapped(sender: MyStaticCell)
}

class MyStaticCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var sendCommentButton: UIButton!

    var delegate: CommentButtonProtocol?

    @IBAction func sendCommentButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.delegate?.commentButtonTapped(self)

    }
}
```

Then in your view controller you can set it as the delegate in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and comply with the protocol in order to handle the event:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CommentButtonProtocol {

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("staticCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyStaticCell
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }

    func commentButtonTapped(sender: MyStaticCell) {
        // Do whatever you need to do when the button is tapped
    }

}
```

Comment: Reading your posts is the most insightful source I've found on Swift Protocols and POP thinking. Thank you!